# Lauching java app at remote URL from windows command prompt

Tags: java, windows-8, jvm

Some instructions I found give the following errer:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=”localhost” GetURL https://some.url.com/someapp/main.jnlp

Error: Could not find or load main class GetURL
```

(The app: If you load the URL in a browser window, it starts the Java app - the app doesn't run in a browser window.  The problem is I need the app to use a proxy, independent of the browsers settings.)

Comment: I don't know if you would be okay with affecting all Java applications.  If so, Java can be configured to use its own proxy settings.  Open the Java control panel (using `jcontrol` in Unix/Linux, or the "Java" icon in the control panel list in Windows), and look for the "Network Settings" button in the General tab.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it seems a Java Web Start application, I think you should use `javaws` instead of `java`, like this:

```
javaws -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=”localhost” https://some.url.com/someapp/main.jnlp
```

Comment: That does the exact same thing as just typing javaws by itself - it loads the splash screen.  The program ip2launcher.exe is not launched.  If I load the URL in a browser window, that program is seen running in the task manager, and the app's window opens.